# iphone - UIImagePicker overwritting geotagging in photo - fixed in os4?

Tags: iphone, exif, geotagging

It is my understanding that currently if you use UIImagePicker to grab a photo, it passes back back a UIImage object which doesn't include any of the geotagging information. I was wondering if it's confirmed that in OS 4 this is fixed? Or any suggestions on where to go look to see if this is fixed?

Thanks, Mark

Comment: I thought the issue was that to do anything with the image you need to convert it to NSData and it was this operation that removed the gettagging info. I've read this, but not tested it. If its true, its likely that that will remain as an issue in the future. I'll keep an eye on this to see what other say!

Comment: Is this really a bug? Seems to me it would be designed this way, since  being able to get the images geotags would allow applications to retrieve your geographic location without having been given explicit access to CoreLocation features in the standard fashion. My 2 cents.

Comment: What about in situations where you want to use a photo uploading app and keep your photos exif information intact for say geolocating in flickr? And what about situations where you are uploading photos you took a month ago, you couldn't grab the phones current location because it wouldn't be accurate anymore... anyway I can see the privacy issue, but still seems like there isn't a way to upload a photo and keep the geotagging info without downlaoding the photos to your desktop first.

Answer (score 0):

I found an app call PixelPipe that retains the geotag information. Give that a try. I'd like to use the native Flickr app if it supported geotag retention.

Answer (score 0):

The new lower level AVFoundation calls provide means to get metadata along with image data.